# Does Pyspark ML KMean have a way to get the explained variance?

Tags: python, pyspark, k-means

As I was reading through the ML package for Pyspark [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.clustering.KMeansModel), it seems the KMeanModel doesn't have a way to compute the explained variance in order to draw an elbow curve, to establish the optimal number of clusters.

However in [this](http://takwatanabe.me/pyspark/generated/generated/pyspark.ml.clustering.KMeans.html) example, the user seems to have a `computeCost()` function. Where did that function come from? I'm not having success in my program.

I am using Spark 1.6. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was stuckked with same issue regarding **computcost** method in pyspark.

Instead of using the computecost you can use **mahalanobis distance or WSSE** after applying kmeans.

> To compute the distance you have to write the code and and getting the
>   various result you can draw the graph to see the knee point for
>   optimum number of cluster .

[Anomaly Detection Using PySpark](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/anomaly-detection-using-pyspark-hive-and-hue-on-amazon-emr/)  this use case which helped me have a look.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it seems computecost is available >2.0? I went ahead and implemented my own.